# carousel de Boostrap 4 no funciona

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

Hola tengo un problema usando el codigo de https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/carousel/

se queda fija la imagen que esta activada y no pasa a la siguiente, comprobé tener todas las librerías y las tengo a todas

aqui les dejo el codigo que use

```
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="01.png" class="img d-block w-100" alt="...">
              </div>
                <img src="02.png" class="img d-block w-100" alt="...">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="03.png" class="img d-block w-100" alt="...">
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Si el código que copiaste en la pregunta es tal cual el de tu proyecto entonces te falta abrir el div que pertenece al segundo carousel-item, el fallo en la estructura provoca obviamente fallos en la funcionalidad

Comment: saludos, fijate que tienes el cierre de un div demas a la altura de "02.png" o te falta el de apertura del mismo

Answer (score 0):

Primero: Te falta cerrar el div principal

```
 <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
```

Segundo: Te falta encerrar en un div con **carousel-item** a uno de tus slides

```
<div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="02.png" class="img d-block w-100" alt="...">
</div>
```

El final debería verse así

```
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="01.png" class="img d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>

            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="02.png" class="img d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>

            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="03.png" class="img d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```